# I need to access files for processing. The files have the same data but have different delimiters types (spaces,commas,tabs) per line

Tags: python, delimiter

I need to access files for processing. The files have the same data but have different 
delimiters types (spaces,commas,tabs) per line.

My code is the following:

```
import os
import glob

DIR = "directory_path"
FILES = glob.glob(os.path.join(DIR, "*"))

for file in FILES:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        content = open(file).readlines()
        for lines in content:
            line = lines.split(" " or "\t" or ":")
            .
            .
            .
            "processing content of line"
```

The lines are splitting fine for " " case but not for other cases. How do I handle different delimiters.

Comment: Make sure to provide relevant sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the re module and utilize its split capabilities to split the lines of your file.

```
import re
import os
import glob

DIR = "directory path"
FILES = glob.glob(os.path.join(DIR, "*"))

for file in FILES:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        content = open(file).readlines()
        for lines in content:
            line = re.split(r'[\s,\t]\s*',lines)
            .
            .
            .
            process content per line
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)

```
import re

line = re.split("\s+|:",lines) # pass different delimiters using  |
```

The `|` basically means or, so split on any whitespace or on a `:`

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in content:
    split_line = re.split("[ \t:]",line)
```

I think is what you want